# One_Hot Encode and Tensorflow (Explain behind the scenes )

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, one-hot-encoding

I am new to deep learning world and tensorflow. Tensorflow is so complicated for me right now.

I was following a tutorial on TF Layers API and I got this issue with one hot encode. Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

wine_data = load_wine()
feat_data = wine_data['data']
labels = wine_data['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feat_data,
                                                labels,
                                                test_size=0.3,
                                               random_state=101)


scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_x_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
scaled_x_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
# ONE HOT ENCODED
onehot_y_train = pd.get_dummies(y_train).as_matrix()
one_hot_y_test = pd.get_dummies(y_test).as_matrix()


num_feat = 13
num_hidden1 = 13
num_hidden2 = 13
num_outputs = 3
learning_rate = 0.01

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,num_feat])
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,3])

actf = tf.nn.relu

hidden1 = fully_connected(X,num_hidden1,activation_fn=actf)
hidden2 = fully_connected(hidden1,num_hidden2,activation_fn=actf)
output = fully_connected(hidden2,num_outputs)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=y_true, logits=output)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

training_steps = 1000
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)

     for i in range(training_steps):
         sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:scaled_x_train,y_true:y_train})

     # Get Predictions
     logits = output.eval(feed_dict={X:scaled_x_test})

     preds = tf.argmax(logits,axis=1)

     results = preds.eval()
```

When I run this code I got this error

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (124,) for Tensor
>   'Placeholder_1:0', 
>       which has shape '(?, 3)'

After a little digging I found that modifying `sess.run` to

```
sess.run(train,feed_dict{X:scaled_x_train,y_true:onehot_y_train})
```

and changing `y_train` to `onehot_y_train` made the code run

**I just want to know what is happening behind the scenes and why is the one_hot encoding that necessary in this code?**

Answer (score 1):

Your network is making a class prediction on 3 classes, class A, B, and C.

In defining a neural network to transform your 13 inputs to a representation that you can use to distinguish between these 3 classes you have a few choices.

You could output 1 number. Let's define a single-value output <1 represents class A, an output between [0,1] is class B, and an output >1 is class C.

You could define this, use a loss function like square error, and the network would learn to work under these assumptions and probably do half way decently at it.

However, that was a rather arbitrary choice of values to define 3 classes, as I'm sure you can see. And it's certainly sub-optimal. Learning this representation is harder than it needs to be. Can we do better?

Let's pick a more reasonable approach. Instead of 1 output we have 3 outputs. We define each output to represent how strongly we believe in a particular class. In order to conform to the cross entropy loss you use we'll further constrain those values to be in the range [0,1] by applying a sigmoid to them. So great, we now have 3 values in range [0,1] that each represent the belief that the input should fall into each of our 3 classes.

You have labels for each of your inputs, you know for sure that these inputs are class A, B, or C. So for a given input that is say class C, your label would naturally be [0, 0, 1] (e.g. you know it's not A or B, so 0 in both of those cases, and 1 for C which you know the class to be). Voila, you have the one-hot encoding!

As you might imagine this is a much easier problem to solve than the first one I presented. Hence we choose to represent our problem this way because we end up with networks that perform better when we do. It's not that you couldn't represent it another way, you just want the best results possible and one-hot encoding typically performs above other representations you might dream up.